# Calling if __name__ == '__main__': in one module from a function in another module

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, module, program-entry-point

I need to call `if __name__ == '__main__'`, that calls several classes in one module, `Module 1`, in a function, `function1`, that's in a class in a second module, `Module 2`.

I can't use `def main()`- solution in `Module 1` instead of `if __name__ == '__main__'`, since the module has several classes and functions connected to `Class_1` in `Module 1` that only works with `print('I am:', __name__)` and `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

So my question is how I can call main: `if __name__ == '__main__'` from `Class_1()` in `function1` in `Class_2()` in `Module 2`?

**Module 1**

```
print('I am:', __name__)

class Class_1():
   ....code...

# calling everything in the module that
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

**Module 2**

```
# if __name__ == '__main__' from Module 1 should be called in function 1


class Class_2():
   .... code..

   def function1:
    --- calling main if __name__ == '__main__' from Module 1
```

Comment: ...what?! You can't *call* `if __name__ == "__main__"` - it's not a function.

Comment: I could call it as in a main function but I'm getting a lot trouble with the script in Module1 when I change it from  if __name__ == "__main__" to def main() in order to call Module1.main() in function1 in Class_2, Module2, so that's why I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code using `main` and explain exactly what's wrong with it (inputs and full traceback or expected and actual outputs)? What you are trying here is not going to work for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `if __name__ == '__main__'` is mainly used to make a single python script executable. For instance, you define a function that does something, you use it by importing it and running it, but you also want that function to be executed when you run your python script with `python module1.py`.

For the question you asked, the best I could come up with is that you wanted a function defined in "module1.py" to run when you invoke "module2.py". That would be something like this:

```
### module1.py:
def main():
    # does something
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

### module2.py:
from module1 import main as main_from_module_one

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_from_module_one()  # calling function main defined in module1
```

Answer (score 1):

The *whole point* of the `if __name__...` is that it's for things that are only needed when the module is executed as a script, ie exactly if it's *not* being imported from another class. So no, you don't need to do this.

Your explanation of why you can't put things into a function make no sense; that is exactly what you should do.

Comment: Pardon for being unclear, my intention is to import the script in Module1 into Module2 and not the other way around. The script in Module1 with if __name__ == "__main__" should only be called in function1 in Class_2, Module2

Comment: @user1749431 then you shouldn't be using `if __name__ == "__main__"` *at all*; that is for when the module **isn't** imported.