# Calling __main__ from another file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a file named `client_simulator.py`  and it contains a Class named `Client_simulator` which simulates clients behavior.

I  have another file named `pool_manager.py` and it has no class, it has one `__main__` and lot of functions and basically, I want to call a method named `generator` of `Client_simulator class` from one of the methods of `pool_manager.py`.

[image]

the basic structure of `client_simulator.py` is as follows

```
class Client_simulator(object):
    def generator(self):

if __name__ == '__main__':
Client_simulator().generator()
```

the basic structure of file `pool manager.py` is as follows

```
def start_client_simulator():

     client_simulator.Client_simulator().generator()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   start_client_simulator()
```

I am getting the following error

`'module' object is not callable`

P.S: I want to call `__main __` instead of `generator()', how to do that?

I am recently moving from java to python that's why having these basic doubts.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand . Even when you call the main , it had generator call , so it will be called right ? Is that what you want to call the main directly ?

Comment: can you please let me know, how to call main. For example, I tried `client_simulator.main()` but its giving me same error

Comment: using client_simulator.main() gives 'module' object has no attribute 'main'

Comment: Yes. if __name__ == "__main__": this statement checks if the invoking call is from the same program or not.

Comment: You aren't attempting to call a module in the code you show, so it's not clear where your error message is coming from. What are you running that produces the `'module' object is not callable` error, and what is the *exact* error message you get?

Comment: you should create a main function. Though that's not a good practice why not just call another function instead. There is an eval though it's always frowned upon

Comment: When you ask a question about an exception, include the traceback.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71967141/1364242

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're confused a bit, at least in terminology if maybe not in code.

When you guard a section of code with `if __name__ == "__main__":`, you're not defining a `__main__` function. It's just a normal `if` statement that reads the global variable `__name__` (which is set up by the Python interpreter automatically) and compares its value to a string.

So there's no `__main__` to be called from another module. If you want the contents of that block to be callable from elsewhere, you should put it in a function, which you can call from both the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block and from the other module, as necessary.

So try this in `client_simulator.py`:

```
class Client_simulator(object):
    def generator(self):

def main():    # you can name this whatever you want, it doesn't need to be main()
    Client_simulator().generator()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The `pool_manager.py` file can call `client_simulator.main()` too.

Answer (score 7):

@blckknght is right, but if you absolutely do need to do that, use below antipattern

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run('python D:/your_script.py')
```